# Is this a mistake of missing preposition?

Tags: prepositions

A sentence [on this page](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-out) strikes me as odd as I am checking dictionaries

> She wasn’t allowed go out and play with the other kids.

Am I correct in saying this sentence needs the preposition **to** after **allowed** and should be:

> She wasn’t allowed **to** go out and play with the other kids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, it should be:

> She wasn’t allowed **to** go out and play with the other kids.

Answer (score 2):

- She wasn't **allowed out** to play.
- She wasn't **allowed to go out** and play.

Both are correct.